# onmouseover not working in IE10?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-10, onmouseover

I'm having an issue with getting onmouseover to work with IE10. I am using it to change the images on the nav bar when the user rolls over them. Works fine in chrome/firefox..

Here is the link to the page I'm currently working on:

http://www.moonandfox.com/test_dir/djink/home.html

Any ideas on how I can modify so that it works in IE? Or is there a better way of going about doing something that has the same effect?

Thanks!
Rachael

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate you can use some third party Javascript library like JQuery, YUI, etc to handle all the user events/clicks. Benefits of using 3rd party tool is you don't have to worry about compatibility issues and plus you will get lot of additional features.
1) http://jquery.com/
2) http://yuilibrary.com/

Comment: Ok thanks, I will modify it so that I'm using JQuery. Good to know that will eliminate compatibility issues. Still at a loss as to why this doesn't work in IE10... but I suppose a lot of what IE does causes some head scratching.

Comment: It's very hard to debug issues with IE so people always prefer to go with other libraries. But you can try doing like:

idNav.onmouseover= callFunction;

callFunction() {
....
...
}